# Ctag error with vim - E431: Format error in tags file - spf13 bundle

Tags: vim, ctags

Updated with new error:

I have installed the following VIM bundle/package
http://vim.spf13.com/#vundle on my Mac OS X

I installed crags with

> /usr/local/bin/ctags
>   --langmap=php:.engine.inc.module.theme.install.php --php-kinds=cdfi --languages=php --recurse -f

The error I get is

```
E433: No tags file 
E426: tag not found: get_aflex_now
```

So when I remove all the following lines, CTAGS starts to work.. Trying to figure out what's causing the problem in the following code

```
" Modeline and Notes {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  " vim: set sw=4 ts=4 sts=4 et tw=78 foldmarker={,} foldlevel=0 foldmethod=marker spell:
  "
  "                    __ _ _____              _
  "         ___ _ __  / _/ |___ /      __   __(_)_ __ ___
  "        / __| '_ \| |_| | |_ \ _____\ \ / /| | '_ ` _ \
  "        \__ \ |_) |  _| |___) |_____|\ V / | | | | | | |
  "        |___/ .__/|_| |_|____/        \_/  |_|_| |_| |_|
  "            |_|
  "
  "   This is the personal .vimrc file of Steve Francia.
  "   While much of it is beneficial for general use, I would
  "   recommend picking out the parts you want and understand.
  "
  "   You can find me at http://spf13.com
  " }

  " Environment {

      " Identify platform {
          silent function! OSX()
              return has('macunix')
          endfunction
          silent function! LINUX()
              return has('unix') && !has('macunix') && !has('win32unix')
          endfunction
          silent function! WINDOWS()
              return  (has('win16') || has('win32') || has('win64'))
          endfunction
      " }

      " Basics {
          set nocompatible        " Must be first line
          if !WINDOWS()
              set shell=/bin/sh
          endif
      " }

      " Windows Compatible {
          " On Windows, also use '.vim' instead of 'vimfiles'; this makes synchronization
          " across (heterogeneous) systems easier.
          if WINDOWS()
            set runtimepath=$HOME/.vim,$VIM/vimfiles,$VIMRUNTIME,$VIM/vimfiles/after,$HOME/.vim/after
          endif
      " }

  " }

  " Use before config if available {
      if filereadable(expand("~/.vimrc.before"))
          source ~/.vimrc.before
      endif
  " }

  " Use bundles config {
      if filereadable(expand("~/.vimrc.bundles"))
          source ~/.vimrc.bundles
      endif
  " }

  " General {

      set background=dark         " Assume a dark background
      " if !has('gui')
          "set term=$TERM          " Make arrow and other keys work
      " endif
      filetype plugin indent on   " Automatically detect file types.
      syntax on                   " Syntax highlighting
      set mouse=a                 " Automatically enable mouse usage
      set mousehide               " Hide the mouse cursor while typing
      scriptencoding utf-8

      if has('clipboard')
          if LINUX()   " On Linux use + register for copy-paste
              set clipboard=unnamedplus
          else         " On mac and Windows, use * register for copy-paste
              set clipboard=unnamed
          endif
      endif

      " Most prefer to automatically switch to the current file directory when
      " a new buffer is opened; to prevent this behavior, add the following to
      " your .vimrc.before.local file:
      "   let g:spf13_no_autochdir = 1
      if !exists('g:spf13_no_autochdir')
          autocmd BufEnter * if bufname("") !~ "^\[A-Za-z0-9\]*://" | lcd %:p:h | endif
          " Always switch to the current file directory
      endif
    " }

  " }

  " Use before config if available {
      if filereadable(expand("~/.vimrc.before"))
          source ~/.vimrc.before                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      endif
  " }

  " Use bundles config {
      if filereadable(expand("~/.vimrc.bundles"))
          source ~/.vimrc.bundles
      endif
  " }

  " General {

      set background=dark         " Assume a dark background
      " if !has('gui')
          "set term=$TERM          " Make arrow and other keys work
      " endif
      filetype plugin indent on   " Automatically detect file types.
      syntax on                   " Syntax highlighting
      set mouse=a                 " Automatically enable mouse usage
      set mousehide               " Hide the mouse cursor while typing
      scriptencoding utf-8

      if has('clipboard')
          if LINUX()   " On Linux use + register for copy-paste
              set clipboard=unnamedplus
          else         " On mac and Windows, use * register for copy-paste
              set clipboard=unnamed
          endif
      endif

      " Most prefer to automatically switch to the current file directory when
      " a new buffer is opened; to prevent this behavior, add the following to
      " your .vimrc.before.local file:
      "   let g:spf13_no_autochdir = 1
      if !exists('g:spf13_no_autochdir')
          autocmd BufEnter * if bufname("") !~ "^\[A-Za-z0-9\]*://" | lcd %:p:h | endif
          " Always switch to the current file directory
      endif

      "set autowrite                       " Automatically write a file when leaving a modified buffer
      set shortmess+=filmnrxoOtT          " Abbrev. of messages (avoids 'hit enter')
      set viewoptions=folds,options,cursor,unix,slash " Better Unix / Windows compatibility
      set virtualedit=onemore             " Allow for cursor beyond last character
      set history=1000                    " Store a ton of history (default is 20)
      set spell                           " Spell checking on
      set hidden                          " Allow buffer switching without saving

      " Instead of reverting the cursor to the last position in the buffer, we
      " set it to the first line when editing a git commit message
      au FileType gitcommit au! BufEnter COMMIT_EDITMSG call setpos('.', [0, 1, 1, 0])

      " http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restore_cursor_to_file_position_in_previous_editing_session
      " Restore cursor to file position in previous editing session
      " To disable this, add the following to your .vimrc.before.local file:
      "   let g:spf13_no_restore_cursor = 1
      if !exists('g:spf13_no_restore_cursor')
          function! ResCur()
              if line("'\"") <= line("$")
                  normal! g`"
                  return 1
              endif
          endfunction

          augroup resCur
              autocmd!
              autocmd BufWinEnter * call ResCur()
          augroup END
      endif

      " Setting up the directories {
          set backup                  " Backups are nice ...
          if has('persistent_undo')
              set undofile                " So is persistent undo ...
              set undolevels=1000         " Maximum number of changes that can be undone
              set undoreload=10000        " Maximum number lines to save for undo on a buffer reload
          endif

          " To disable views add the following to your .vimrc.before.local file:
          "   let g:spf13_no_views = 1
          if !exists('g:spf13_no_views')
              " Add exclusions to mkview and loadview
              " eg: *.*, svn-commit.tmp
     "set autowrite                       " Automatically write a file when leaving a modified buffer
      set shortmess+=filmnrxoOtT          " Abbrev. of messages (avoids 'hit enter')
      set viewoptions=folds,options,cursor,unix,slash " Better Unix / Windows compatibility
      set virtualedit=onemore             " Allow for cursor beyond last character
      set history=1000                    " Store a ton of history (default is 20)
      set spell                           " Spell checking on                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
      set hidden                          " Allow buffer switching without saving

      " Instead of reverting the cursor to the last position in the buffer, we
      " set it to the first line when editing a git commit message
      au FileType gitcommit au! BufEnter COMMIT_EDITMSG call setpos('.', [0, 1, 1, 0])

      " http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restore_cursor_to_file_position_in_previous_editing_session
      " Restore cursor to file position in previous editing session
      " To disable this, add the following to your .vimrc.before.local file:
      "   let g:spf13_no_restore_cursor = 1
      if !exists('g:spf13_no_restore_cursor')
          function! ResCur()
              if line("'\"") <= line("$")
                  normal! g`"
                  return 1
              endif
          endfunction

          augroup resCur
              autocmd!
              autocmd BufWinEnter * call ResCur()
          augroup END
      endif

      " Setting up the directories {
          set backup                  " Backups are nice ...
          if has('persistent_undo')
              set undofile                " So is persistent undo ...
              set undolevels=1000         " Maximum number of changes that can be undone
              set undoreload=10000        " Maximum number lines to save for undo on a buffer reload
          endif

          " To disable views add the following to your .vimrc.before.local file:
          "   let g:spf13_no_views = 1
          if !exists('g:spf13_no_views')
              " Add exclusions to mkview and loadview
              " eg: *.*, svn-commit.tmp
              let g:skipview_files = [
                  \ '\[example pattern\]'
                  \ ]
          endif
      " }

  " }
```

Comment: That's what she said! Yea it's 96 megs. It's a large project...

Comment: Please, find the corresponding line in your tags file and append it to your question.

Comment: Check it out. I updated it..

Comment: @Carpetsmoker There is nothing unusual about tags files that are a few hundred megabytes in size.